# NGROK Browser Warning Bypass

Tags: linux, debian

I have an ngrok server running and I wanted to bypass this warning so what do I put in my request to bypass this?

I'm a newbie involved with this kind of stuff.

I do not know if I'm on the wrong stack exchange Q&A.

[image: NGROK Browser Warning]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73844702/4481226